# VUE How can I do click in image and redirect to page?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, buefy

I would want to add link in image. How can I do click in "fork me..." and redirect to http?

I'm using Vue.
[image]

```
<div class="menu">
   <div>...navbar...<div>
   <div class="forkme">
      <img class="forkmeFigure" src="@/static/forkme-dark-background.png">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add an anchor as wrapper:

```html
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
  <img class="forkmeFigure" src="@/static/forkme-dark-background.png">
</a>
```